# jsPDF - Getting black images on IE, but works fine on Chrome and FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, jspdf

I need some help with the following problem, when I get a pdf with images on Chrome and FireFox I can get a good résult, jsPDF put on it some blur but I can live with it.

[Result on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy4W7.jpg)

In other hand, on IE 10,11 and Edge the result is the following:

[Result on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0diY.jpg)

If you notice we can see something on pictures but almost is black.

Those are charts from highcharts and I convert svg to canvas.

I put some snippets but I can send to email the whole example:

```
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
  var centered_x = (doc.internal.pageSize.width / 2) - ((context.destWidth / 2) * 0.75);

imgData_1 = atob(imgData_1);
doc.addImage(imgData_1, 'png', centered_x, 50);

data.datauri = context.browserSupportDownload && doc.output('datauristring');
data.blob = context.browserSupportBlob && doc.output('blob');
```

I call the function `download` to send the stream to the browser and its definition is like that:

```
  var download = function(highChartsObject, context, data) {
    if (!data || (!data.content && !(data.datauri || data.blob))) {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong while exporting the chart");
    }

    if (context.browserSupportDownload && (data.datauri || data.content)) {
      a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = data.datauri || ('data:' + context.type + ';base64,' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data.content))));
      a.download = 'result_good.pdf';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      a.remove();
    }
    else if (context.browserSupportBlob && (data.blob || data.content)) {
      blobObject = data.blob || new Blob([data.content], { type: context.type });
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, 'IE_CASE.pdf');
    }
    else {
      //window.open(data);
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, 'IE_CASE.pdf');
    }
  };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you use Highcharts exporting module in this case? http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background color of the image using canvas or svg.
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/247

Comment: Thanks for your response, now I use the method save of jsPdf which works fine with chrome and fireFox and IE 10 as well, the problem still happen with IE edge.

Best regards