# Set text color of my jsPDF object doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, colors, jspdf

I have a small piece of text that represents the status of something on my pdf. I want the text Fail to be red with a red circle next to it, while having Pass be green text with a green circle. This works perfectly fine in chrome and firefox, but shows up black in IE (working with version 11, but probably occurs on everything below as well).

This is the relevant code:

```
if(status === Status.FAIL){
     pdf.setTextColor("#ff0000")
     pdf.setFillColor("#ff0000")
}
else if(status === Status.PASS){
     pdf.setTextColor("#00ff00")
     pdf.setFillColor("#00ff00")
}
else if(status === Status.WARNING){
     pdf.setTextColor("#FFD700")
     pdf.setFillColor("#FFD700")
}

pdf.text(status, 747, offset);
pdf.circle(740, offset - 3.5, 5, "F")
```

[IE Generated PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P94M.png)

[Literally every other browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2gBW.png)

Comment: Appropriate you showed the `fail` case - because, fail and internet explorer are synonymous. Is this the only place in the document you deal with colour or is this the only place in the document you have an issue with colour?

Comment: I can't help but wonder why on earth they're so different in size. It makes me wonder if you've made an unrealised mistake in your code or this question, since colour is but one of the differences. 12px text versus 14px. 18px diameter versus about 20px diameter. This thread talks of similar issues (with the library, surely) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805961/jspdf-getting-black-images-on-ie-but-works-fine-on-chrome-and-firefox

Comment: Lol this is the only part of the code that seems to have this problem with color. but im only using it in 2 places. Also i have no idea what youre talking about the difference in size... those are images...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RGB instead of Hex code when setting color. I made a demo to set color of jsPDF objects and it works well in IE and Chrome:

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.js"></<>script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></<>script>
    <script>
        function init() {
            var doc = new jsPDF();

            doc.setFillColor(255, 0, 0);
            doc.circle(20, 20, 2, 'F');

            doc.setTextColor(255, 0, 0);
            doc.text(24, 21.5, 'Fail');

            doc.setFillColor(0, 255, 0);
            doc.circle(20, 30, 2, 'F');

            doc.setTextColor(0, 255, 0);
            doc.text(24, 31.5, 'Pass');

            doc.setFillColor(255, 215, 0);
            doc.circle(20, 40, 2, 'F');

            doc.setTextColor(255, 215, 0);
            doc.text(24, 41.5, 'Warning');

            doc.save('Test.pdf');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
</body>
```